# Kann »von wegen« ein Zitat einführend neutral fungieren?

Tags: single-word-request, idiom, style

Öfters habe ich *von wegen* in einem Kontext gehört, welcher eine Erklärung von Dritten einleitet. Ich weiß aber nicht, ob das regional ist.

Auf [Redensarten-Index](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=von%20wegen&bool=phrase&gawoe=an&suchspalte[]=rart_ou) steht:

> 2. fügt man hinzu, wenn man wiedergibt, was jemand anderes gesagt / geschrieben hat.

und beispielsweise:

> *Dann klingelt das Telefon, er ruft mich zu sich ins Zimmer und macht mich blöd an, **von wegen** er wäre mit meiner Arbeitsleistung absolut nicht zufrieden.*

Da steht aber nicht, ob die Person, die das Zitat wiederholt, eine voreingenommene Meinung zu der Behauptung hat. Wirkt *von wegen* neutral? D. h.:

- Kann man *von wegen* nutzen, ohne seine eigene Meinung (sei es Zustimmung oder Unglaubwürdigkeit) auszudrücken?

Und daher, kann man es, etwa in diesem Fall, durch **weil er meint** wie folgt ersetzen?

> *Dann klingelt das Telefon, er ruft mich zu sich ins Zimmer und macht mich blöd an, **weil er meint**, er wäre mit meiner Arbeitsleistung absolut nicht zufrieden.*

<sup>**Edit:** Das erste Beispiel vor dem Edit war</sup>

> <sup>Sie schrie mich an, von wegen sie hätte Vorfahrt gehabt, ich solle meine Daten rausrücken usw.</sup>

Comment: Randbemerkung: Meinem Verständnis nach ist ein Zitat immer eine "exakte Wiedergabe", daher handelt es sich in deinem Beispiel nicht um ein Zitat. Man hört aber auch schon mal von "sinngemäßen Zitaten", wobei das meines Erachtens ein Fehler ist. Aber das tut's hier nicht wirklich zur Sache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, *von wegen* ist in diesem Sinn neutral. Der Beispielsatz eignet sich zwar nicht sehr gut, um das zu zeigen, da der Sprecher vermutlich nicht die Unzufriedenheit des Chefs bezweifeln würde und aus der Formulierung *blöd anmachen* schon hervorgeht, was er von der Kritik hält; aber wenn man diese Elemente aus dem Satz entfernt, kommt eine neutrale Wiedergabe dessen dabei heraus, was der Chef gesagt hat.

> Er spricht mich an, von wegen ich würde neuerdings nur noch Müll abliefern.

Hier markiert *von wegen* in erster Linie den Beginn von indirekter Rede. Eventuell kann es noch einen Hinweis geben, daß das Zitat nicht wörtlich so gefallen ist.

*Von wegen* in dieser Verwendung ist stark umgangssprachlich. In Standardsprache würde man es einfach weglassen oder, wenn man die Ungenauigkeit des Zitats betonen will, *sinngemäß* sagen:

> Er spricht mich an, ich würde neuerdings nur noch Müll abliefern.
>   Er spricht mich an und sagt sinngemäß, ich würde neuerdings nur noch Müll abliefern.

---

Ein „weil er meint“ einzufügen, ist prinzipiell möglich, verändert aber den Sinn: Erstens gibt man damit eine Begründung (warum spricht der Chef mich an?), statt ihn einfach zu zitieren; zweitens wird aus der indirekten Rede, also der Wiedergabe des *Gesagten*, eine Wiedergabe des *Gedachten*. Bekanntlich kann beides auseinanderfallen:

> Er spricht mich an, weil er meint, ich würde neuerdings nur noch Müll abliefern, und sagt, meine Arbeit wäre ganz hervorragend.

Dieser Satz setzt natürlich übersinnliche Fähigkeiten (Gedankenlesen) beim Sprecher voraus.

Answer (score 3):

> Sie schrie mich an, von wegen sie hätte Vorfahrt gehabt.

*Von wegen* kann hier weggelassen und der restliche Satz durch *sie hätte Vorfahrt gehabt* ersetzt werden.

Der Teil hinter *von wegen* gibt den Inhalt des Geschrienen wertneutral an in Form indirekter Rede.

Allerdings antworte ich darauf (Die Verwendung (1)):

> Von wegen Sie haben Vorfahrt gehabt.

Und teile der Frau damit mit, dass ich vom Gegenteil überzeugt bin.

> Die Frau schrie, von wegen ich hätte Vorfahrt gehabt.

Damit teilt sie mir mit, dass sie mit der Aussage, ich hätte Vorfahrt gehabt, nicht einverstanden ist.

Die Verwendung von *von wegen* ist daher sehr kontextabhängig. Im ersten Fall macht es tatsächlich keinen Sinn, anzunehmen, dass die Frau ihre eigene Aussage und Überzeugung vehement bestreiten würde, da sie ja im original nach den Papieren des Schuldigen fragt.